# pdfmerger - foreach value create object PHP?

Tags: php, forms, object, foreach, set

Please excuse my lack of terminology and knowledge of PHP I am pretty inexperienced with it.
I have this PHP sample from the pdfmerger open source code.

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf ->addPDF('samplepdfs/page1.pdf' , 'all')
     ->addPDF('samplepdfs/page2.pdf' , 'all')
     ->merge('download', 'mypdf.pdf' );
```

I would like to create this dynamically from a form. So when someone selects from the form that they want both pages and click submit it goes through the posted array and adds the pages for every value in the array.

So the form would look something like this:-

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
Page1? : <input name="Page1" type="checkbox" value="one.pdf" /><br><br>
Page2? : <input name="Page2" type="checkbox" value="two.pdf" /><br><br>
Document Name? : <input name="name" type="text" value="MYPDF1.pdf" /><br><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I would like the php to go through the values and do something like the below which I know is incorrect.

```
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$name = $_POST["name"];

$arr = $_POST;

$pdf = new PDFMerger;

$pdf 
foreach($arr as &$value){
 ->addPDF('samplepdfs/' . $value , 'all')
};
    ->merge('download', $name );
```

This would mean I could add as many items to the form and it would allow the user to select any combination of pdf's from the form and they would be merged.

I know this is wrong but I cannot find (as I dont really know what to search for) anything that has helped me figure it out.

Also, how would I stop the loop from getting the name (the last value in the loop) as I want to add this manually to the ->merge object.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would advice you to hire a freelancer. The members of stackoverflow will not do work for you, if you have a more concrete example of what you have achieved and there is a error of some kind in that, the members will be able to help.

Comment: I don't want to hire a freelancer I want someone to point me in the right direction as to where I might find some answers to my question so I can learn myself. Thanks.

Comment: Well looking at what you have produced so far, i would suggest you start learning with much more simple code. Start by learning loops and if logic, than the stuff you want to achieve will follow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I do want to learn it for myself but i am struggling to know what I need to be searching for. I think I need a for each loop within an object? But this doesn't bring anything up. Would you be willing to point me in the right direction? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated

I dont think you are too far off in your thinking, something like below should get you on the right track
 notes: the input name "page[]" will store the values in an array, you will have to dynamically generate the labels (e.g. Page1?, Page2?) & values (e.g. one.pdf, two.pdf) for the inputs, so as to make the form more dynamic i.e. not having to add rows manually every time a new document is added.

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    Page1? : <input name="page[]" type="checkbox" value="one.pdf" /><br><br>
    Page2? : <input name="page[]" type="checkbox" value="two.pdf" /><br><br>
    Document Name? : <input name="name" type="text" value="MYPDF1.pdf" /><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
include 'PDFMerger.php';

$name = $_POST["name"]; // add some validation and / or sanitise here

$pageArray = $_POST['page']; // add some validation and / or sanitise here

$pdf = new PDFMerger;
foreach ($pageArray as $value) {
    $pdf->addPDF('samplepdfs/'.$value, 'all');
}
$pdf->merge('download', $name);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - I did actually do it like this at one point (using page[]) but didn't use it to split the rest of the values from the name value, so that is a good tip. 
There is a syntax issue because there is no ; after the line within the loop but adding one prevents it working with the object. 
Thanks a lot for your help - I am using this as a starting point. 
(also, I didnt need '.pdf' in the value of the inputs as well as within the loop.)

Comment: Actually after playing around with this I actually got it working.
Thank you so much for helping! In my needs I need to remove the closing ?> tag and also remove the duplicate '.pdf' info and also add the ; to the line within the loop.